# Using a single clause compute whether the sum of any three members of a list is equal to given value

Tags: list, prolog

We are not supposed to use any of the functions other than the ones listed below:

- A single clause must be defined (no more).
- `+`
- `,`
- `;`
- `.`
- `!`
- `:-`
- `is`
- Lists
- Head and tail syntax for list types
- Variables

For example `sumlists([1,2,3,5,7],11)` then the program execution should print **`TRUE`**. Because 1+3+7 (any three)=11 (given N value).

Comment: A single clause or a single predicate?

Comment: Seem to have already been asked at [Calculate whether the sum of exactly three values in a list is equal to N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168962/calculate-whether-the-sum-of-exactly-three-values-in-a-list-is-equal-to-n). But the answers there don't conform to the requirements. Still, the way of SO suggests we post answers there, and close this one as a duplicate. (?) Especially since there's no attempted code included in *this* question.

Comment: I've decided to post an answer here, because the proposed duplicate asks about *its* included user code. my answer just answers the question.

Comment: @PauloMoura judging by the proposed use of `;`, single predicate with a single clause. Not even grouping parens  `(`, `)` are allowed. :)

Comment: Have you made any specific attempts at your assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, we either get an element or don't, as we go along the input list; and we stop either on having reached the needed sum, or having surpassed it, or when the list has been exhausted.

But we can only have one clause one predicate here, and only use certain primitives, so instead we sneakily use `+` both symbolically, to gather the information for summation, and as an arithmetic operation itself:

```
sumlists(L, N) :-
      N = X+A+B+C, X is A+B+C, !
   ;  L = [H|T], sumlists(T, N+H)
   ;  L = [H|T], sumlists(T, N).
```

Comment: This is a really fantastic trick! Tracing the execution was really fun. Thank you for taking the time to share this!

Comment: @DanielLyons thanks, had fun myself, :) mainly because of the requirements. To collect "elts chosen so far" we seemingly need third argument, so, another predicate... Could subtract the chosen elt from the target instead, but `-` isn't allowed... Then, the light-bulb: *Symbolically* subtracting is collecting; and `+` or `-`, symbolically, doesn't matter! The lesson: "delayed evaluation to the rescue!" Almost like Reynolds' defunctionalization, even... Very good exercise. (Couldn't get it fully deterministic though, with the requirements)